# Is my cactus okey?

Tags: cactus

This is my first time posting thing here n honestly the only reason I'm signing up on this website is to find out on what the hek is wrong with my cactus. So please??? I had been searching on Google about the condition of my cactus but I don't really know what to type since English is not my main language. Any suggestions or advice will do![image]

Comment: Welcome Caccy! I'm glad you found us and hope we help you. We'd really like it if you like the site and stay. If not, you can always come back if you end up with another plant question!

Answer (score 2):

To start with, it needs far more sun than it is receiving now. The stretching and the pinch in the body are all due to lack of sufficient sunlight. Cactus (generally) need direct sun for 5 or more hours per day. Otherwise it looks fairly healthy, nice and green, not lacking water, no apparent pests.